# Problems with modules after installing a new perl

Tags: perl, perlbrew

Until recently I exclusively used perl 5.18 under perlbrew on Mac OS X.

I installed perl 5.20 under berlbrew in order to try waack https://github.com/yanick/waack (very cool, BTW), and had to reinstall a few modules (DBI, Sub::Base) under the new perlbrew with cpanm.

Since then, if I try to work under 5.18, I seem to get problem with every non-pure-perl module.

I can see that XS portions of modules are not installed under the version-dependent perl, like in this case:

```
~/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-2level/auto/Sub/Name/Name.bs
```

and I see that I also have an older version installed under the right perlbrew like this:

```
~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/darwin-2level/auto/Sub/Name/Name.bs
```

Any idea of what mess I've gotten myself into? and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest testing your installs first.

```
$ perlbrew switch perl-5.18.2
$ cpanm --interactive -v App::cpanoutdated
$ cpan-outdated
$ cpanm --interactive -v App::CPAN::Fresh

$ perlbrew switch perl-5.20.0
$ cpanm --interactive -v App::cpanoutdated
$ cpan-outdated
$ cpanm --interactive -v App::CPAN::Fresh
```

Source: [Kent's blog](http://blog.fox.geek.nz/2010/09/installing-multiple-perls-with.html)